# KivyMD FileManager abilities

Tags: python, android, ios, kivy, kivymd

I am looking to have a button that allows a user (Ios or android) to select a photo in their library and have it be saved to be sent off later. I am using the filemanager to open the manager. How specifically could I use file manager to accomplish this?: (Code below, note the second screen is a part of a larger concept and not the entire app):

```
.py
```

> class SecondScreen(Screen):

```
 def select_path(self, path):


  self.exit_manager()
  toast(path)


  def exit_manager(self, *args):

  self.manager.dismiss()
  self.manager_open = False




  def file(self):
      path = '/'  
      file_manager = MDFileManager(
      exit_manager=self.exit_manager,  
      select_path=self.select_path, 
     )
      file_manager.show(path)
```

.kv
#under a screen labled with class

```
           MDFillRoundFlatButton:
                text: 'Click here'

                font_size: 20
                on_press: root.file()
```

All is formated correctly top work but all it does is open file manager on pc and let me browse all my files. When hitting 'X' to exit an error pop up saying something like 'manager does not have property .dismiss()'. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Though Kivy(MD)'s FileManager is good, there is actually a better alternative which is from the [plyer module](https://github.com/kivy/plyer), specifically the  `filechooser` API. What it does is to open up the default file manager app of your device to either choose folder, file or save file. Here is an example:

.py

```
def open_file(self):
    path = filechooser.open_file()[0] 
    # this method returns a list with the first index
    # being the path of the file selected
    print(path)

def open_file(self):
    path = filechooser.choose_dir()[0] 
    print(path)
```

.kv

```
MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    text: 'Open an image:'

    font_size: 20
    on_press: root.open_file()

MDFillRoundFlatButton:
    text: 'Choose a directory:'

    font_size: 20
    on_press: root.choose_folder()
```

More information regarding the APIs of this library [here](https://plyer.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

Notes:

1. This file chooser is very weak on the Windows platform, so I would recommend using `tkinter`'s `filedialog` if you need to.

<s>2. Isn't it already obvious that it's not gonna work on iOS?</s>
It might work on iOS, but only opens an image selector

Comment: thank you for the help! I never thought of the tkinter approach. What do you mean by 'not gonna work on ios'?

Comment: There's 2 reasons for that: 1. Plyer doesn't support native file chooser for iOS; 2. iOS has storage access fully disabled by default, only images and videos are accessible (at least that's what I believe, I don't use iPhone), so it's pretty obvious how a file chooser is not going to iOS any time soon. Hope this helps!

Comment: it does help thank you :) so just to clarify if i use file chooser a user would only be able to choose videos or photos?

Comment: about that... no..., plyer doesn't support that at the moment I believe. I might will search for something similar later

Comment: After doing some searching, I found out that the filechooser's methods do take *args and **kwargs, and one of them is actually a file filter. So, if you want to have your file chooser only looking for videos and images, you can do something like this: `path = filechooser.open_file(filters=[["Music", "*mp3", "*ogg", "*aac"], ["Image", "*png", "*jpg"]])[0]`. Another note is that while iOS doesn't support file selection, I read plyer's source code and found out that it might be able to open an image selector, though I'm not sure and I don't have the facility to test them out.

Comment: Awesome and no worries I will test it out and report back. Thank you so much